# How would I write 5 eighth notes (as one note, and ties are ok) in 6/4 time signature?

Tags: theory, time-signatures

I'm not sure if i should write it as an eight note tied to a dotted eight note, or maybe a half note tied to a 16th note or what I don't know.

Comment: Welcome! The answer would depend on context, and what part of a beat the note begins on. By the way, an 8th tied to a dotted 8th is only 2.5 eighth notes, and a half note tied to a 16th is 4.5. Are you sure that "five eighth notes" is the value you want?

Comment: It's unclear to me what do you want to achieve. Is it a homework problem?

Answer (score 3):

First, 5 eighth notes is not either of the values you mentioned in your question as pointed out in comments. There are several different combinations possible to get a note that is 5 eighth notes in duration. A half tied to an eighth and a dotted quarter tied to a quarter are the most common and logical.

The other issue is 6/4 time. In 6/4 time you want beat 4 (the middle of the bar) to be visible since 6/4 implies 2 groups of 3 quarter notes. This will determine the note values used for a note of that length.

Here are examples of notes on and off various beats that are 5 eighth notes long in 6/4 time. For simplicity I used all quarter rests instead of half and dotted half rests:

[image]

Examples 1-4 start on Beats 1-4 respectively. Note that example 3 has a quarter tied to a dotted quarter to show beat 4.

Examples 5-8 start on 1&, 2&, 3&, and 4& in that order. Also note that example 6 has a dotted quarter tied to a quarter to show beat 4.

Comment: The groups of three quarter-note rests would be easier to read as dotted half-note rests. (Gould p.161)

Comment: @PiedPiper I agree but I thought it would be better for the OP to be able to see every beat.